# Move different UIView In UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, subview

In my iOS application i have a scrollview in which there are many imageviews and textviews.
I have to move all this views down to a fixed value, but i don't want to move them to left, right or resize them. I just want to move them down, on an event. The problem is that i can't know which are the values of these UIView.

This is my code:

```
for(UIView* subview in [myScrollView subviews])
{
    subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
}
```

i'd like to do this:

```
for(UIView* subview in [myScrollView subviews])
{
    subview.frame = CGRectMake(previousValue+100, previousValue, previousValue, previousValue);
}
```

I hope I explained myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to move them down, why don't you just set scrollView's contentInset?

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, previousValue, previousValue, previousValue);
```

this will make all your subViews down.

Comment: I can't, i want to move these views down because i have to insert other views at the top of the scrollview

Comment: ok, in this situation you do not reset frame of your subView. just set your subView: `subView.center = CGPointMake(subView.center.x,subView.center.y+50)`so you don't have to know any values of these subViews.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
UIView *lastView;
for(UIView* subview in [myScrollView subviews])
{
    CGrect lastFrame;
    if (!lastView) {
        lastFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100); // your initial frame
    } else {
        lastFrame = lastView.frame;
    }
    lastFrame.origin.x += 100;
    subview.frame = lastFrame;
    lastView = subview;
}
```